# How do I Play audio on server in Blazor App

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to make a jukebox device to play audio, with LAN users accessing a Blazor app to select songs.  This could be either Windows or Linux server.

I have tried many tutorials on playing audio, but they are all made to play on the client, but nothing to play audio server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at nAudio. I'm pretty sure the server will have to be Windows.

Comment: Thank you.  So, I added Naudio via Nuget.  I then changed the "counter" page to this code below.  What is the path that Naudio is looking for this file?  I tried wwwroot, and the server root.

Comment: `code

@page "/counter"
@using NAudio.Wave
@using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders

@code {
    private WaveOutEvent? outputDevice;
    private AudioFileReader? audioFile;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        if (outputDevice == null)
        {
            outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
        }
        if (audioFile == null)
        {
            audioFile = new AudioFileReader("a.mp3");
            outputDevice.Init(audioFile);
        }<br/>
        outputDevice.Play();
    }
}

`

Comment: After thinking about what your trying to accomplish, you may have all kinds of issues trying to play it directly inside a Blazor server call. I would look at creating some kind of queueing mechanism - a simple SQL table would do. Have the Blazor app add the next song to the table. Then write a client app or Windows service that would load the song and play it. Web servers aren't really designed to play audio and your going to run into some strange lifecycle and concurrency issues.